# Java real-time service monitoring framework

Tags: java, performance, monitoring, jmx, snmp

Got to create some kind of "counters" for online service monitoring - i.e. Foo_Request_Total, Foo_Request_DB_error, Foo_Request_Timedout, Bar_Request_Total,...

Also, some kind of alarm has to be generated when counter passes a pre-defined limit 
(for example SNMP trap if more than 5 requests per hour were timed out).

Could you suggest any Java framework for this ?

Comment: did you found a framework to go with?

Answer (score 1):

The standard monitoring mechanism in Java is [JMX](http://java.sun.com/javase/technologies/core/mntr-mgmt/javamanagement/).

You can monitor services remotely and even execute commands.

There are JMX/SNMP connectors you can use to map values to a MIB and generate traps.

Comment: I am looking for a framework to collect the data and manage some rules (limits/thresholds). Collected data will be indeed retrieved via JMX.

Answer (score 0):

How about http://perf4j.codehaus.org/index.html or https://github.com/earnstone/eperf?